# mediawiki add <script> to <head> section

Tags: php, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki site and I'm trying to add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the `<head>` section of the page. 
I can't figure out how to do it. 
I've tried adding

```
$wgResourceModules['ext.mobile'] = array(
    'scripts' => array('filename')
```

to the extension and I've tried adding

```
$out->addScript('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>');
```

to the skin but it isn't showing in the view source. 
How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to load jQuery anyway? MediaWiki [already includes it](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JQuery).

Comment: It does? I code doesn't run if I don't include the file.

Comment: With just "doesn't run", it's hard to say anything much. Is there an error message on the JS console? What jQuery features are you using? Maybe you need to list some additional [modules](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Default_modules) as [dependencies](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader#Registering).

Answer (score 0):

```
$wgResourceModules['ext.mobile'] = array(
    'scripts' => array(
    'toggle.js',
    'jquery1.js',
```

seems too work, I didn't have the array() syntax correct which was why it wasn't working the first time and it doesn't appear in view source  section so it is confusing as well.